# JDBI: Long/Interger exception when inserting data

Tags: java, dropwizard, jdbi

I want to insert a  row into a maraiDB database with JDBI/Dropwizard.

My table was generated with

```
CREATE TABLE parameter (
  job_id INT  references job(id),
  name VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
  content VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL
);
```

and use an interface to insert data in to the database

```
  @SqlUpdate("INSERT INTO parameter (job_id, name , content) VALUES " +
 "(:job_id, :name , :content)")
  long insert(
      @Bind("job_id") int job_id, 
      @Bind("name") String name, 
      @Bind("content") String content);
```

now when I call the method via

```
private final ParameterJDBI parameterJDBI;
public void insert() {

      parameterJDBI.insert(1, "name", "value");

  }
```

I get an error

```
ERROR [2018-06-14 15:39:46,083] io.dropwizard.jersey.errors.LoggingExceptionMapper: Error handling a request: 700d318fa5724df6
! java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
```

I also changed the signature to long and changed the first argument to `1L` but the error still persist. I dont understand where the long object comes from.

Comment: Can you try defining job_id as a long?

Comment: I also did that. I tried both. And get the same error

Comment: You pass `parameter`, but call insert on `parameterJDBI`. Is that intentional?

Comment: job_id is a foreign key to the job table, can you update the question with job tables structure, i think there is a mismatch in the type

Answer (score 1):

You are using @SqlUpdate which returns an int(the number of updated/inserted rows).So, your method declaration should return int or void.

If you want to return the key(s) generated from the SQL statement, then you should add [@GetGeneratedKeys](http://jdbi.org/#__getgeneratedkeys_3)